# Use a logical vector with sapply

Tags: r, sapply

I am trying to use a logical vector to 'tell' sapply which columns to make numeric in my dataset.

In my data, there are NAs but all the variables are either numeric or character. I'm taking the first complete case (hard code below, but would love suggestions!) and making a logical vector based on if the first character in the string is numeric or a letter. I would like to use that logical vector to tell sapply which columns to make numeric.

```
#make data frame, this should return an all 'character' data frame
color <- c("red", "blue", "yellow")
number <- c(NA, 1, 3)
other.number <- c(4, 5, 7)
df <- cbind(color, number, other.number) %>% as.data.frame()

#get the first character of the variables in the first complete case
temp <- sapply(df, function(x) substr(x, 1, 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  .[2,] %>% # hard code, this is the first 'complete case'
  gather() %>%
  #make the logical variable, which can be used as a vector
  mutate(vec= ifelse(value %in% letters, FALSE, TRUE)) # apply this vector to sapply + as.numeric to the df
```

Comment: `df <- data.frame(color, number, other.number)` Will guess the type for you.

Comment: I would not follow that route but to pick up where you left off, `df[temp$vec] <- lapply(df[temp$vec], as.numeric)` - Which will work **IF** your original variables are characters and not factors

Comment: You really don't need a `data.frame` to hold the `logical` vector. Try: `isnum <- sapply(df, is.numeric); df[isnum] <- lapply(df[isnum], as.numeric)`.

Comment: thank you @Sotos I did have options(stringsAsFactors= F) and should have put that in. Your solution works. How would you approach the problem?

Comment: thanks @troh and r2evans as well. There were other issues (taken care of in previous data prep) that kept the variables from being detected automatically on read-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strange case, but If you need to convert numeric columns based on their first element, then an idea would be to convert it to numeric. Since any element that is not a number will return `NA` (as the warning states), you can use that to index. For example,

```
ind <- sapply(na.omit(df), function(i) !is.na(as.numeric(i[1])))
```

> Warning message:
>       In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

```
ind
#       color       number other.number 
#       FALSE         TRUE         TRUE 

df[ind] <- lapply(df[ind], as.numeric)

str(df)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ color       : chr  "red" "blue" "yellow"
# $ number      : num  NA 1 3
# $ other.number: num  4 5 7
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(color = c("red", "blue", "yellow"), number = c(NA, 
"1", "3"), other.number = c("4", "5", "7")), .Names = c("color", 
"number", "other.number"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```